# BackboneJS .ajaxStart() and .ajaxStop() while fetching collection

Tags: ajax, backbone.js

I have a BackboneJS App where I fetch a bunch of collections. Now I want to apply some sort of loader to indicate that the collection is loading and the user gets to know that something is happening. So I want to use the `.ajaxStart()` and `.ajaxStop()`-method. So I was thinking about something like this:

```
this.artistsCollection.fetch(
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    console.log('ajax start');
           $('.someDiv').addClass('TEST');
}),
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    console.log('ajax stop');
           // stop doing stuff
})
);
```

Issue is that first time I trigger the .fetch() my console says `ajax stop` and the class is not applied!?!?  Second time I trigger the .fetch() it works like it should and the class gets applied. Does anyone know whats the issue?

Please help anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the returned result of adding the two event handlers with jQuery as parameters to the Collection `fetch` method. The Backbone Collection `fetch` method receives an options object which can include a success callback (see [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch)).

I think if you move the listeners out of the method call it should work as you expect:

```
// Global AJAX listeners
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
    console.log('ajax start');
            // do stuff
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    console.log('ajax stop');
           // stop doing stuff
});

this.artistsCollection.fetch();
```

Comment: Hmm ok, I edited my question a bit, so I tried to do your example but still it does not solve the issue, regarding applying the class first time I trigger the fetch().

Comment: Does the log statement get fired?

Comment: Not the first time, there it only says `ajax stop` - but second time, and all after that it says both

Comment: That's odd. Are you able to put together a basic http://jsfiddle.net which demonstrates the problem?